# An easier way to store and check if the incoming Id is a MongoDB ObjectID with Pydantic and FastAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, fastapi, pydantic

I am currently handling incoming requests in a FastAPI application, and I want to ensure that the str value representing a user ID in the request path is a valid bson.ObjectId. Currently, I have a custom Pydantic model and a validation class to achieve this.

Here's the existing code:

```py
from typing import Any

from bson import ObjectId
from pydantic_core import core_schema
from pydantic import BaseModel

class PyObjectId(str):
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
            cls, _source_type: Any, _handler: Any
    ) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        return core_schema.json_or_python_schema(
            json_schema=core_schema.str_schema(),
            python_schema=core_schema.union_schema([
                core_schema.is_instance_schema(ObjectId),
                core_schema.chain_schema([
                    core_schema.str_schema(),
                    core_schema.no_info_plain_validator_function(cls.validate),
                ])
            ]),
            serialization=core_schema.plain_serializer_function_ser_schema(
                lambda x: str(x)
            ),
        )

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value) -> ObjectId:
        if not ObjectId.is_valid(value):
            raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")

        return ObjectId(value)
    
class MyClass(BaseModel):
   id: PyObjectId 

# Define the APIs
@router.get("/user_id/{id}")
async def get_user(id: str):
    body = MyClass(id=id)
    return body.id
```

Is there a more efficient or standard way to validate and store the `bson.ObjectId` directly in a Pydantic model? I want to ensure that the ID is valid and use it for various functionalities, such as querying the database.

I would like to also avoid `body = MyClass(id=id)` if that would be possible, but I don't think `pydantic` would allow that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Annotated` type and plug in custom validation with `AfterValidator`. For example:

```py
from typing_extensions import Annotated
# or `from typing import Annotated` for Python 3.9+
from pydantic import AfterValidator


def valid_bson(value: str) -> ObjectId:
    if not ObjectId.is_valid(value):
        raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")

    return ObjectId(value)

@router.get("/user_id/{id}")
async def get_user(id: Annotated[str, AfterValidator(valid_bson)]):
    return id
```

See the pydantic documentation: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/types/#custom-types